# How can I share files between Bitnami Hadoop VM and Windows host machine?

Tags: windows, virtual-machine

I have been trying to have a way to share files between Bitnami Hadoop on a virtual machine and windows host machine but I have not found a concrete way to do this. Any ideas please?

I tried using the shared folders option but it did not work.

Comment: What do you mean "share"? `hadoop fs put` command is how you *add* files to hadoop. They'd then be distributed into blocks, so not a file format that windows could read/share on its own. VM or not, doesn't matter and using VM features wouldn't be correct solution

Answer (score 0):

To connect to the Hadoop File System, you need a client that implement the gRPC protocol for HDFS.
You can also enable WebHDFS, which is a service running on the server that exposes HDFS via a REST API, but you still need a client application to connect to it.

Shared folders in Windows use the WebDAV protocol, which is also over HTTP, but is not the same as WebHDFS, so it will never work with Hadoop.

Cloudera has a web application that acts as a File Browser for Hadoop, running in a browser, but that's part of their Cloudera Manager tool, I think.

There exists Java-based desktop applications that allow you to browse Hadoop, e.g. https://github.com/sdadas/fsbrowser.

Or you can use one of the HDFS Python client libraries, e.g. https://hdfscli.readthedocs.io/

Comment: Question wasn't asking about hdfs. At least, that's not what shared folders in a VM will use

Comment: As you said in your comment: VM features wouldn't be the correct solution, so my answer is more correct, no?